# quarkus 2.1.1.Final ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal

Tags: quarkus

I`m developing an comandline application based with quarkus 2.1.1.Final. When I run **mvnw test**, I'm getting **ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal** and quarkus doesn't start.

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.1.Final:generate-code (default) @ sqlcobol ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sqlcobol ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ sqlcobol ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.1.Final:generate-code-tests (default) @ sqlcobol ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ sqlcobol ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sqlcobol ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ sqlcobol ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running 

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/FastThreadLocal
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal
```

The pom.xml dependencies are:

```
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.1.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
<!--  <quarkus-plugin.version>1.13.7.Final</quarkus-plugin.version> -->
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-picocli</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
      <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.uwol</groupId>
      <artifactId>proleap-cobol-parser</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.1</version>  
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

It looks like it needs additional dependencies. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix put

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml